# Git commit message messed up when stored in a variable

Tags: git, bash, github, git-commit

I have a Git commit, which has a summary, and then some description. So when I see the commit message via `git log --format=%B -n 1 <commit>`, it looks like this:

`Commit Summary Line
* Commit Description Line 1
* Commit Description Line 2
* Commit Description Line 3`

When I try to store this in a Bash variable, however, thus:

`message=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 <commit>)`

and then I try to `echo $message`, I get the folder names from my current directory mixed with each of the lines from the commit message. What's more, I am not even seeing all lines from the commit message, just some of them. So, `$message` looks something like this:

`Commit Summary Line folder1 folder2 folder3 Commit Description Line 1 folder1 folder2 folder3 Commit Description Line 3`

Is there any explanation for this behavior? I just want `$message` to have all lines from the full commit message. I don't even care if they are in new lines or all in one line, I just want all lines stored in a string variable. How do I achieve this?

Comment: As I always say, when in doubt ... quote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bit of rogue [pathname expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) at play here caused by the `*`. Try adding a pair of quotes around your `message` variable and you should be good!

```
echo "$message"
```

Comment: In shell scripts, using variables without protecting them withdouble-quotes is almost always a mistake -- there are many ways for things to go wrong!

Comment: @GordonDavisson – wise words my friend! I cannot count all the times missing quotes have ruined my day.