# redirect the sql query will add all the files in that directory

Tags: sql, bash

I have shell script as below

```
query="SELECT * from [myDB.myTable]"
echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")'|'land'|'Failure'|||'twice'|'$query > test.log
```

When I run above in some directory in my Unix PC, the **test.log** shows the result as below

```
2017-12-13 06:54:03|land|Failure|||twice| SELECT temp1.txt test tmp.log tt.sh from [myDB.myTable]
```

Actually I wanted query to be redirected as it is in the log file, instead it printed all the file names of that directory.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: As I always say, when in doubt ... quote it!

Comment: Just put a set of double quotes around the echo expression and you are good! (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784319/git-commit-message-messed-up-when-stored-in-a-variable/47784488#47784488)

Comment: @TravisClarkeThanks. It works :)

Comment: Np. Green check me (i.e. accept answer) and I'll be on my way. lol. But on a serious note, always using double quotes is a good habit! Especially if the expression contains a `*`, `?`, or `[`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dreaded [pathname expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) strikes again! You can attribute that list of filenames to having a `*` in an unquoted expression.

```
echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')'|'land'|'Failure'|||'twice'|'$query" > "test.log"
#    ^                                                                ^  

cat "test.log"
> 2017-12-13 06:54:03|land|Failure|||twice| SELECT * from [myDB.myTable]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for your complete `echo`, the single quotes can be deleted:

```
echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")|land|Failure|||twice|${query}" > test.log
```

I also have put curly braves in `${query}`, that is not a solution for your problem but a good habit for future scripts.